# Switch between tabs in gnome-terminal with keyboard?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

Once I've created a new tab in `gnome-terminal` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, how can I switch back and forth between the tabs using the keyboard? For example, in Google Chrome the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (forward) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (backward).

I'm using Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon.

Comment: Yea i'm using gnome-terminal ... I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Google returns [THIS](http://superuser.com/questions/130560/how-do-i-alternate-tabs-in-linux-gnome-terminal) as the first result when doing a search with your exact title.

Comment: Thanks. I previously searched for "Switch between tabs in terminal with keyboard" which gives a bunch of results relevent to mac os. I forgot to search again after you asked if I was using gnome terminal.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> (forward) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> (backward).

Comment: If you happen to be on a laptop that has arrow keys, you may need to combine this with the `fn` key

Answer (score 39):

Try using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab number</kbd> for Linux with gnome.

Comment: This works fine for me in `gnome-terminal`. Nice tip!

Comment: Works on xfce terminal. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me! Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you have more than 9 tabs open?

Answer (score 0):

For me, what works is: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab number</kbd>.

Comment: that not work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, only without pressing `<Shift>`

Answer (score 0):

For my Dell XPS 13 2021 laptop it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>up/down arrow</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that your answer is likely only a minor variation of the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67963/377345). To make it more relevant, consider at least stating the laptop model to which your answer applies.